# Access contentWindow of iframe with blank src in ie9 on Twitter

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe, cross-domain

I'm trying to access the inside of a dynamically inserted iframe (inserted from a script that was loaded from a different domain than the host page) in ie9 on twitter.com so that i can write content into it. I tried setting the `src` to both `''` and `about:blank`. Accessing the `contentDocument` throws an `Access denied` error, and accessing the `contentWindow` returns nothing. Why is this and is there a way around it? It works in other browsers, but for some reason is seems that Twitter might be doing something to prevent this and I'm curious as to what it is.

Comment: Can you give some more specific code for what you are trying to do?

Comment: Likely dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14715427/cant-access-an-aboutblank-iframe-in-ie-after-the-document-domain-changes, fixed in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following and I believe it works on all browsers that support `iframe`.

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var iframeDoc = iframe.contentWindow.document;

iframeDoc.open();
iframeDoc.write(html);
iframeDoc.close();
```

I don't set `@src` at all.

Comment: try doing that on twitter.com